# What is the peak time when most number of people are online in PSE?

Tags: discussion

I just want to know, usually at what time the most number of people come online, so I can have more interaction with them?When I am typing , I found very less people answering questions. People who uses this website are not equally distributed all over the globe. So there should be sometime where most of them are active in this website. Someone might be having this statistics. Share if possible.

Answer (score 3):

For real-time interaction, it's chat you want.

Not the main site.

Not this meta site.

But chat. That's what it's there for.

And on the [chat info page](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/71/the-h-bar) for the chat room you're interested in (e.g. the main physics chat room), you can find statistics about number of visitors by hour of the day, and by day of the week.

Answer (score 3):

You can get information on the time of day when questions and answers are posted from the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, using e.g. [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/91524/activity-by-utc-hour#graph). Based on this metric, the most active time is around 1600 UTC. It should also be possible to add in the times when comments are posted if you're interested.

There is no data available on page views with better than daily resolution, at least not through the tools SE provides.

Comment: Or, dare I say, should we look at [comments](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/edit/91532#graph)? Nice peak at 16 UTC as well ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As a side note to David's answer: Trying to figure out when most people are online isn't really the best way to get answers to your questions. If you ask really nice questions, more people will vote/answer. You may want to read [how to ask](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) to help improve your questions :)